# Another r cannot be resolved to a variable/error parsing xml junk after document element

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, defined

I know this is asked a lot but I got error parsing xml junk after document element problem and then after while of looking for the problem I got 10 r can not be defined errors i think it all resulted from the first error. But even when I remove the problem paragraph and click clean the error red x is still there on a blank area.The error started on the textview line at the bottom.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type a Command"
    android:password="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="Try Command" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:checked="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
 android:text="invalid"
 android:id="@+id/tvResults"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />   
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" />
```

should be

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >
```

Notice no `/` at the end of the tag.  The `/` at the end is xml for "close this tag right now please." As it stands, you have invalid xml with two open tags for LinearLayout but closing LinearLayout 3 times.

Comment: @user1854482 The issue is still almost what digitaljoel said. You closed a linearlayout you never opened.

Comment: there's a second linearlayout opening in the first one i think im relatively new to this

Comment: Yes, you have two opening tags, but 3 closing tags. `<LinearLayout ... >` opens the first, `<LinearLayout ... />` opens AND closes the second. `</LinearLayout>` closes the first. The final `</LinearLayout>` closes one you never opened and makes your xml malformed.

Comment: i changed that and cleaned it but the xml error beside the textview opening tag is still there

Comment: please update the question with your new xml and the specific error message after performing and update/clean/build in eclipse.

Comment: "error parsing xml:junk after document element" and i updated the code

Comment: Thanks for your help after restarting eclipse the errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what is the problem when you don't provide the full `xml` file. You probably forgot to close one of your `LinearLayout` items.

edit:

simply delete the `/` character from your `LinearLayout` declaration:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >
```

Comment: i changed that and cleaned it but the error marker beside the text view opening tag is still there as well as all the r errors in the java that i think are caused by this xml error

Comment: put your mouse over the error mark to see what is the error. The R errors in the code will disappear when there will be no errors in the res folder and an R file will be generated.

Comment: "error parsing xml:junk after document element" and i updated the code

Comment: Thanks for your help after restarting eclipse the errors went away.